# Difference between sequence of functions and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I am currently studying uniform and pointwise convergence and I am stuck at a somewhat basic distinction. Until now our lecturer has been talking about sequences of functions. For example:

$$f_n(x)=\frac{n}{x} \space \space \text{or} \space \space f_n(x)=x^n$$

However, in our problem set I am supposed to test the following series for uniform convergence:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nt)}{e^n}$$

Are sequences of functions and series related? Is the process of showing uniform convergence different for series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From any series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$, you can construct the sequence of partial sums,
$$ S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k, $$
and treat it as you would a sequence. Conversely, given any sequence $(b_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$, the differences
$$ a_0 = b_0, \quad a_k = b_k-b_{k-1} $$
can be made into a series,
$$ b_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k. $$
This is much like differentiation and integration being "inverse operations" (scare quotes required for technical reasons, of course).

Comment: So in your example $S_1$ would be equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{1}a_K$; $S_2=\sum_{k=0}^{2}a_K$? Am I basically looking at the sequence of sums?

Comment: Aside: What is a series itself? I think that a sequence is well-defined mathematical object but series is not.

Comment: Why is a series not well-defined?

Comment: @Rzeta: So how do you define a series?

Comment: $\sum_0^n a_n=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n$?

Comment: @Rzeta: That's a picture representing a sum of a finite sequence. But what is a series itself as a mathematical object?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer that.

Comment: @Rzeta: That's why I think that a series isn't well defined mathematical object. On the other hand, sequence is just a function with natural numbers as a domain. But my original comment was just a side note.

Comment: I see. I think I need to open another question with a much longer opening post. I think I should clarify my confusion and give a more concrete example. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Rzeta: I think that your question is ok. I just wanted to make this side note, because I think that people usually don't think about the phenomenon that a series is actually not well-defined mathematical object. :-)

Comment: Yes I understand. It wasn't because of what you said it is because I realized that I had a lot more that I wanted to ask and that I am unsure about. :)

Comment: @Rzeta Your question, phrased in the right way, is perfectly reasonable. I suggest you ask it, that you might receive an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can view a series as a sequence of partial sums.  Try to think of the sequence of functions 
$$f_i(t)=\sum_{n=0}^i \frac{\sin(nt)}{e^n}  $$

Comment: How would I prove/disprove uniform convergence in this case. As far as I know I always need some sort of a limit function when I am trying to test uniform convergence but In this case I am not sure how to even get to that limiting function.

Comment: @Rzeta: You don't need the limiting function. There are theorems you can use to prove that a series is convergent. In this case we have $|\sin(nt) / e^n| ≤ 1 / e^n$ and $∑_n 1 / e^n$ converges, so the original series converges uniformly.

Comment: @user87690 Can you name me some of the theorems. Is the Weierstrass-M-test one of them? I just came accross that while researching. Also, is there any way I can apply things like the ratio test or the root test when testing for uniform convergence?

Comment: @Rzeta: Yes, Weierstrass-M-test is one of them and that's actually what I've used above. It says that if $|f_n(t)| ≤ a_n$ for every $n, t$ and $∑_n a_n$ converges, then $∑_n f_n(t)$ converges uniformly. You use things like the ratio test and the root test to show that your series $∑_n a_n$ chosen for Weierstrass actually converges.

Comment: That actually helped me a ton. Things are starting to fall into place ;). So basically I just have to be "skilled" at choosing an appropriate convergent $\sum_n a_n$ for the Weierstrass-M-test and I am done?